# Difference between localhost 3000 and 5000?

Tags: node.js, flask, localhost, web-development-server

While using NodeJS, the URL was localhost:3000 and while using flask, it was localhost:5000. Why are they different if both running on same browsers. What is the key difference? Are there any others in different web technologies? Can we run NodeJS on 5000 and flask on 3000?

Comment: there is NO difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are they different if both running on same browsers.What is the key difference?

A port is simply a channel of communication which is numbered between 1 and 65000. All network devices use them and most have the ability to change them when required. They were originally created to allow multiple programs to use the same IP address. `The only difference is they use different ports`.

> Are there any others in different web technologies? Can we run NodeJS
> on 5000 and flask on 3000?

Yes, you can run your processes on any port except the `reserved` ports - `0 to 1023`. You need to pass the port number to these processes provided that port is open.

There are several tutorials out on web where you can learn about ports. You can check [one](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/network-layer/what-is-a-computer-port/) here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, you can change the port for nodejs and flask server.
The reason to have different might be to avoid conflicts between the other services running on the machine.